# Are these functions surjective and/or injective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

1. $f : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ defined by $f(n, x) = \dfrac{x}{2n}$
2. $f : \mathbb{R} × \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x, n) = ⌈x-n⌉$

I started out my tests for being surjective by letting an arbitrary integer $y$ be an element of the target set. i.e., $y ∈ \mathbb{Q},~ y ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

For question 1, if I simply said:

Let $y ∈ \mathbb{Q}$

$f(1,2y) = 2y/2*1  = y $

would that be enough?

Additionally, I am rather confused on how to prove if the functions are injective.
My proofs have always started like so:

Let $(a,b), (c,d) ∈ \mathbb{Q}$  s.t $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$
But I am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is fine and it proves indeed that the first $f$ is surjective. But it is not injective since, for instance, $f(1,1)=f(2,2)$.

And neither is the second $f$ since, for instance, $f(1,1)=f(2,2)$ (again!).

Comment: Thank you! Would I be able to prove that the second f is surjective by the same process?

Comment: No! The second one is **not** surjective, since each number of the form $\lceil x-n\rceil$ is an integer. So, for instance, $\frac12$ does *not* belong to the range of $f$.